# Using .NET Core DLL in a UWP Application - Runtime Version Mismatch

Tags: c#, .net-core, uwp, windows-10-universal, .net-framework-version

I have an application that is built on UWP. I need to reference a DLL from a .NET Core Project within my UWP Windows Application Targeted Universal Windows 10.0

The .NET CORE application had a target Core framework 1.0 to match with the UWP 10.0.

I was able to import the DLL, Call it in the application and the application compiled fine. But during execution, when I was using those specific functions, I got a RunTime error as below.

Any help wil be much appreciated.

> System.IO.FileLoadException   HResult=0x80131040   Message=Could not
>   load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)   Source=   StackTrace:

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff .NET Core class library is incompatible with UWP.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for your comments. But, I think a .NetCore Library can be imported in a UWP application.  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bethmassi/understanding-net-2015/

Comment: That MSDN article was written long before .NET Core became a real product. Only information after June 27, 2016 is valid.

Comment: Why am I able to import the library within the UWP and still able to instantiate the class and call all its functions? And yet still be able to compile it without issues?

Comment: When you say "import" do you mean loading the assembly at runtime, or do you mean referencing it at compile time?

Comment: The tooling is not bug free, so you couldn't expect it to prevent incompatible things from being used. Only when your approach is supported, you can be sure that others have gone that way and relevant bugs have been reported and fixed.

Comment: @BurnsBA: By import, I mean referencing at compile time and I am using the functions from the DLL in my code and it compiles just fine. But throws me this error when the page with the functions are loaded.

Comment: UWP is currently not .NET Core compatible, although that will change going forward (with .NET 5, everything will just run .NET 5). UWP apps can reference .NET Standard 2.0 libraries, so your library should target .NET Standard 2.0 instead (as you mentioned, you are targeting .NET Core 1.0, which should be a subset of .NET Standard 2.0 API-wise).